# Comparing two images with ms_ssim on python

Tags: python, compare, pytorch, tensor, ssim

I want to compare two images but ms_ssim wants 4D tensor

https://pypi.org/project/pytorch-msssim/

I Tried

```
from PIL import Image
from tqdm import tqdm
from pytorch_msssim import ssim, ms_ssim, SSIM, MS_SSIM
import torchvision
import numpy as np

topil=torchvision.transforms.ToPILImage()
totensor=torchvision.transforms.ToTensor()

def ssimcompare(path1:str,path2:str)->float:
    image1 = Image.open(path1)
    image2 = Image.open(path2) 
    #it1=np.expand_dims(totensor(topil(np.array(image1))), axis=0)
    #it2=np.expand_dims(totensor(topil(np.array(image2))), axis=0)
    #it1=totensor(np.expand_dims(np.array(image1), axis=0))
    #it2=totensor(np.expand_dims(np.array(image2), axis=0))
    it1=totensor(np.array(image1))
    it2=totensor(np.array(image2))
    valor=ms_ssim( it1 , it2, data_range=255, size_average=False )
    return valor
```

But I get different errors

```
ValueError: Input images must be 4-d tensors.
TypeError: pic should be Tensor or ndarray. Got <class 'PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile'>.
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'type'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that all these functions (and classes) requires *batches* of images as input. But, since an image is 3D, a batch is 4D.

When you have only one image tensor you can "unsqueeze" it into a one-item batch with

```py
it = it.unsqueeze(0)
```

However, I don't recommend the `pytorch_msssim` package. You should consider the [`piqa`](https://github.com/francois-rozet/piqa) or [`piq`](https://github.com/photosynthesis-team/piq) IQA packages, as they are well documented and have faster implementations.

For example,

```sh
pip install piqa
```

Then, your function becomes

```
from piqa import ssim

def msssim_compare(path1: str, path2: str) -> float:
    image1 = Image.open(path1)
    image2 = Image.open(path2)
    it1 = totensor(image1).unsqueeze(0)
    it2 = totensor(image2).unsqueeze(0)

    return ssim.msssim(it1, it2).squeeze(0)
```